# In ngx-scrollreveal , ngsReveal is Hiding components which should animate on scroll

Tags: html, css, angular, scroll, angular-material

```html
<mat-drawer-container style="text-align: center;" class="example-container">
    <mat-drawer mode="side" #drawer opened>
        <div fxFill class="side-card">
            <mat-card-title ngsReveal>
                <mat-icon>landscape</mat-icon> Property Cloud
                <mat-icon>landscape</mat-icon>
            </mat-card-title>

            <mat-card class="side-menu">
                <mat-card-header>

                    <div class="example-header-image"></div>

                    <mat-card-subtitle></mat-card-subtitle>
                </mat-card-header>
                <hr>

                <mat-card-content>

                </mat-card-content>
                <div style="text-align: center;" class="mt-5">

                    <div class="t-5">
                        <button ngsReveal mat-raised-button><a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="property_feed"> </a>Property feed</button>
                    </div>
                    <div ngsReveal class="t-5">
                        <button mat-raised-button>My Account</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="t-5">
                        <button ngsReveal mat-raised-button>My Properties</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="t-5">
                        <button ngsReveal mat-raised-button> My Wishlist</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="t-5">
                        <button ngsReveal mat-raised-button> Settings and privacy</button>
                    </div>



                </div>
            </mat-card>
           
        </div>
    </mat-drawer>
   
    <mat-drawer-content>
        
        <div fxFill class="main-card">

            <app-header (toggleEmitter)="drawer.toggle()"></app-header>

         <div  fxLayout="row wrap" >
    <div  *ngFor="let ppty of property">
        <div  ngsReveal fxFlex>
            <mat-card   class="property-feed">

                <mat-card-header>
                    <div mat-card-avatar class="avatarImage"></div>
                    <mat-card-title >Card Title</mat-card-title>
                    <mat-card-subtitle >Card Subtitle</mat-card-subtitle>
                </mat-card-header>
                <mat-card-content>
                    <app-gallery ></app-gallery>
                    <h3>some informaion to the end user</h3>
                </mat-card-content>
                <mat-card-footer>

                </mat-card-footer>
                <mat-card-actions>
                    <button matTooltip="If intrested contact seller" mat-fab large color="primary">
                        <mat-icon>thumb_up_alt</mat-icon>
                    </button>


                    <button matTooltip="If intrested add to wishlist" mat-fab large color="warn">
                        <mat-icon>add_shopping_cart</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                    <button matTooltip="View details" mat-fab large color="warn">
                        <mat-icon>unfold_more</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </mat-card-actions>
            </mat-card>
        </div>

        
    </div>

</div>

           
        </div>
       
       
    </mat-drawer-content>

    
</mat-drawer-container>
```

In ngx-scrollreveal , ngsReveal is Hiding components which should animate on scroll.Only components which is within viewport of website is showing and animating. other than cards which should reveal on scroll is hidden.I could see the cards are present there, since i have a click event, its working but components are  hidden. And I couldn't see any console errors.

"./node_modules/scrollreveal/dist/scrollreveal.min.js", is imported in angular.json

Its working for element except in viewport,On later experiemnting by placing content in different places.

div is getting hide because its placed under mat-drawer-content. Any idea why its hiding elements that is not coming at the first time loading.

I could see the difference for this displayed card's html and hidden card's html is different in case of opasity  but dont know what is causing it. Its working fine except inside mat-drawer-container.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgsRevealConfig } from 'ngx-scrollreveal';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-property-feed',
  templateUrl: './property-feed.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./property-feed.component.scss'],
  providers: [NgsRevealConfig] 
})
export class PropertyFeedComponent {

  property =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
  
  }
```

```css
button {
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.feed-title {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Girassol", cursive;
}

.property-feed {
  width: 300px;
  height: 410px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .property-feed {
    width: 300px;
    height: 410px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Answer (score 0):

`[ngsReveal]="{delay: some_delay, reset: false}"`

Try using binding it's properties with html element!
PS: I am not sure that this will work in your scenario or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try add className (button) and add your class name to  container

```
<button class="button" [ngsReveal]="{reset: true, container: '.button'}" mat-raised-button> My Wishlist</button>
```